# TCP socket Client and server in one program using c Linux

Tags: c, tcp

i have a project where in the user can be the client or server. if he use the program first, he will serve as the server then the other one will be the client and vice versa. is there a possible way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the best way, but you can try to bind a server socket to some port and assume that if you can, then you are the server. otherwise, you are the client.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible. Write two separate code for server and  client, use same Port no. in both codes. See this [link for basic code](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/)

Comment: i found a way by making 2 different function (for client and server) where in if the file descriptor of client function is equal -1 (it will be the first one to check), the function client will return 0 then it will trigger the flag that server function will be using.